Looking for a word/phrase for "fidgety"
I am looking for a single word or phrase to describe someone who mindlessly fidgets with things constantly.

Isn't the most apt word in the title?

Nervous? Spectrumy? Keeps busy? Energized? Proverbs' "Idle hands are the devil's workshop"?

What @KillingTime said. Why is "fidgety" not the right word, given that's the only adjective you've given as a clue to the sought term?

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/fidgety

On pins and needles?

See What do you call people who are constantly moving?. [fidgety / antsy] + twitchy, restive, hyper.

Rarely ever is a behavior truly "mindless". The word you're looking for is found in the root and cause of the behavior.
I might describe such a person as nervous, uncertain or insecure.
